# Yelp API access not available

Tags: java, android, yelp

I need Yelp API for using in my Android app. [The form on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5XAa.png)
https://www.yelp.com/developers/get_access 
It requires a website URL. Am I accessing the right form? I don't have a website and I don't need it for a website. From what I understand you need a Key for using it on Android. How can I get that key? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the API requires the website. If you don't have your own website, then you must provide a URL where they can see the description about your application.